# Qual è il significato di "sbruffoneggiare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, neologism

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Lo schifo che mi fa, quando qualcuno chiede quanti figli volete e lui **sbruffoneggia**, dice: domandate a Gigliola, io di figli ne ho già e non so nemmeno quanti sono.

Qual è il significato di "sbruffoneggiare" in questo brano? Secondo [questo articolo](http://www.today.it/cronaca/nuovo-zingarelli-2013.html) si tratta di un neologismo e appare nella nuova edizione dello Zingarelli del 2013, ma questo verbo non si trova in altri dizionari che ho consultato. Qualcuno potrebbe riportare la definizione dello Zingarelli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ecco (questa è la voce come è data nello Zingarelli in rete, aggiornato all'edizione 2017, accessibile solo a pagamento):

> **ṣbruffoneggiàre** /zbruffonedˈdʒare/
>   [1992]
>   **A** v. intr. (pres. *io sbruffonéggio*; fut. *io sbruffoneggerò*; aus. *avere*)
>   ● fare lo sbruffone
>   **B** v. tr.
>   ● dire qlco. vantando meriti eccezionali e inverosimili

Comment: Il termine sembra essere stato inserito nel 2013d "*Tra i neologismi, action movie, arrosticino, banzai, battutaro, booktrailer, campero, cicaleggiare, dissociale, faunista, framework, fumino, inciuciare, nordismo, pagellino, **sbruffoneggiare** e zompettare".*http://www.tg1.rai.it/dl/tg1/2010/articoli/ContentItem-a408c78a-299a-436b-899a-8ca0365f5ce0.html?p=8

Comment: @Gio Mi sembra che l'articolo prenda un bell'abbaglio; "arrosticino" comparirà anche per la prima volta nel vocabolario, ma non mi sembra proprio un neologismo...

Comment: Già, @FedericoPoloni. Oltre a essere ovvio in sé, lo stesso Zingarelli dà, come datazione per “arrosticino”, il 1498. Quell'articolo avrà confuso i neologismi con i nuovi lemmi aggiunti in quella edizione dello Zingarelli.

Answer (score 3):

Probabilmente il verbo deriva dall'aggettivo "sbruffone" che può essere sinonimo di "arrogante" o "presuntuoso"; o meglio, qualcuno che non da peso a ciò che dice vantandosi di cose che in realtà non ha fatto o dicendo di essere ciò che in realtà non è.

In questo caso l'uomo in questione sta alludendo al fatto di non sapere quanti figli abbia come fosse qualcosa di cui vantarsi o esserne fieri, evidentemente per sfoggiare e/o enfatizzare la sua capacità di procreare.

Answer (score 0):

Adesso che abbiamo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI17/GDLI_17_ocr_723.pdf&parola=sbruffoneggiare) in rete, possiamo anche riportare la definizione che dà questo vocabolario:

> **Sbruffoneggiare**, tr.  (*sbruffonéggio*).  Dire  con tono  borioso  e  arrogante  (anche  per  introdurre  il discorso diretto). 
>  
>         *G.  M.  Bellu*  [«La  Repubblica»,  23-IV-1992],  4:  Giovanni Altezio...  sorride  d’un  pasciuto  compiacimento  per  la  ci­tazione  e  sbruffoneggia:  «È  la  prima  volta  che  vengo  qua, anche se faccio politica da sempre». 
>  
>        
>   = Denom. da *sbruffone*, con il suff. dei verbi frequent.

Speravo di trovare questo termine in uno dei [supplementi del 2004 o del 2009](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_dizionario_della_lingua_italiana), però curiosamente l'ho trovata nel volume XVII, cosa che significa che è stata introdotta in questo dizionario molto prima di quando si è fatto nello Zingarelli.

Answer (score -1):

Ecco qua la definizione:

> "sbruffoneggiare" English translationIT
>   "sbruffoneggiare" in English

volume_upsbruffoneggiare {v.i.}
EN
to rodomontade
More information

Translations & Examples
Translations & Examples
IT sbruffoneggiare volume_up {intransitive verb}

sbruffoneggiare (also: fare lo spaccone)
volume_up to rodomontade {vb} [elev.] (talk boastfully)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Mi dispiace, ma non capisco la tua risposta. Sembra un "copy & paste" da non si sa dove senza molto senso.

Comment: Lo era perché non sapevo come "ricapitolare" questa definizione. Comunque, significa "sbruffonare; fare lo  sbruffore, fare lo spaccone".